# Get subquery where clause id match id from main query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to get a value from a column for the current day for each row in the result set, so the best thing I could think of was to to a sub query like this:

```
SELECT ads.ad_id,
       ads.ad_status,
       ads.ad_impression_bid,
       ads.allocated_credits,
       ads.daily_credits,
       ads.used_credits,
       ads.ad_type_id,
       ads.aname,
       at.url,
       adst.text,
       Ifnull(Sum(views), 0)  AS impressions,
       Ifnull(Sum(clicks), 0) AS cliks,
       views,
       clicks,
       view_cost,
       click_cost
FROM   ads
       JOIN ad_targets at USING(ad_target_id)
       JOIN ad_status adst
         ON( adst.ad_status_id = ads.ad_status )
       LEFT JOIN daily_displays using(ad_id)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT views,
                         clicks,
                         view_cost,
                         click_cost,
                         ad_id
                  FROM   daily_displays
                  WHERE  day = Curdate()
                         AND ad_id = ads.ad_id) AS dd using(ad_id)
WHERE  owner_id = 13035
       AND ads.ad_status <> 5
GROUP  BY ads.ad_id
ORDER  BY ads.ad_id ASC
```

When I run it though, I get an error saying `Unknown column 'ads.ad_id' in 'where clause'` and that is in the sub-query but when I comment it out there is no error. Is there something I can do so I can access it?

I would like the `ads_id` in the sub query to match `ads.ad_id` in the main query.

**Edit**

What I am trying to accomplish is combining our code. In php it was written to take one query get a list of all ads a user has then for each ad run 2 queries on it. I want to combine that so if someone has 20 ads it doesn't do 41 queries.

So first our code runs this to get a list of ads:

```
$sql = "SELECT ads.ad_id, ads.ad_status, ads.ad_impression_bid, ads.allocated_credits, ads.daily_credits,
    ads.used_credits, ads.ad_type_id, ads.aname,
    at.url, adst.text
FROM ads
JOIN ad_targets at USING(ad_target_id)
JOIN ad_status adst ON(adst.ad_status_id = ads.ad_status)
WHERE owner_id=" . (int)$_SESSION['vp_member']['member_id'] . " and ads.ad_status <> 5 ORDER BY ads.ad_id ASC";
```

Then for each ad we run these two queries to get information about them:

```
$sql = "SELECT ifnull(SUM(views),0) AS impressions, ifnull(SUM(clicks),0) as cliks FROM daily_displays WHERE ad_id=" . (int)$this->ad_id;
// Run the query and return the data here

$sql = "SELECT views,clicks,view_cost, click_cost FROM daily_displays WHERE ad_id=" . (int)$this->ad_id . " AND day=CURDATE() ";
// Run the query and return the data again
```

I am trying to combine these 3 queries into one query.

Comment: In addition to the posted solution, you will need to alias the columns in your select statement as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to fix this by using a join in the subquery. Running this takes about `0.109 seconds` to run.

```
(
select dd2.views, dd2.clicks, dd2.view_cost, dd2.click_cost, dd2.ad_id from daily_displays dd2
join ads ads2 on(ads2.owner_id = 13035 and ads2.ad_id = dd2.ad_id)
where day = curdate()
) as dd using(ad_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need subquery here, try instead of

```
LEFT JOIN daily_displays using(ad_id)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT views,
                         clicks,
                         view_cost,
                         click_cost,
                         ad_id
                  FROM   daily_displays
                  WHERE  day = Curdate()
                         AND ad_id = ads.ad_id) AS dd using(ad_id)
```

use

```
LEFT JOIN daily_displays using(ad_id)
ON (daily_displays.day = Curdate() AND daily_displays.ad_id = ads.ad_id)
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because I need to sum the other columns, just those four columns I need the current day, everything else needs to be a sum of all time if that makes sense....

Comment: @RyanNaddy you do aggregation (sum + group by) in main query

Comment: @RyanNaddy it works, maybe you have more errors in your sql or just today there were no impressions

Comment: Yeah there were no impressions today, but I need a sum of impressions from the beginning of time.

Comment: @RyanNaddy then you need both join daily_displays 2 times and use proper aliases